# Exercise about the fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm studying the fixed point and I found this exercise on my text book.  I've tried to study the function: $f(x)=x^2+1/4$ and find the possible fixed attracting or repelling point.

Now I find that the fixed point $x=1/2$ but now to prove if it is a repelling or an attracting fixed point it's a little bit difficult.
I've two general definition of this two type of points but I can't find a way to apply it correctly.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\frac{1}{2}$ is an attracting point. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f^n(x)$ tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x\in [\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon].$

However, let $x=\frac{1}{2}+h$ for $\epsilon>h>0$. Then $f(\frac{1}{2}+h)=\frac{1}{2}+h+h^2$ and so  $f(x)$ is further from $\frac{1}{2}$ than was $x$.
Therefore $f^n(x)$ does **not** tend to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore $\frac{1}{2}$ is **not** an attracting point.

Similarly, by using $x=\frac{1}{2}-h$ for $\epsilon>h>0$, you can prove that it is not a repelling point. It is called a **neutral** fixed point.

Comment: Note that $f'(\frac12) = 2(\frac12)=1$ so this is a parabolic fixed point.

Comment: Sorry but I've two definition for this two different points: ATTRACTING if $\exist \epsilon \ge 0$ | $\forall x\in D\cap (p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$ ,$lim_{n \to \inf} f^n(x)=p$ ( where $f^n(x)$ it' not the function elevated but $f(f....f(x))$) while REPELLING if  I have the same conditions of Attracting point but the point have to respect: |f(x)-p|>|x-p|

Comment: What definition do you have that you cannot apply?

Comment: The conditions are in the previos comment

Comment: Neither of the two conditions hold for this function and so the function is neither repelling nor attracting.

Comment: But how can apply it?

Comment: I have applied your definition in an edit.

Comment: Yes, but you don’t have used the limit and so on :/

Comment: I am proving that $\frac{1}{2}$ is **not** the limit. If $x<f(x)<f(f(x))< ...$ then $x$ cannot be the limit.

Comment: I’m very very sorry with you but I’m studying like a self-taught so it’s difficult for me to understand so immediately this things. So, if it’s not a problem, can you write it more complete? So maybe I can understand better.

Comment: I've added as full a proof as anyone could expect for the proof that it is not attracting.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: I hope this has helped your studies.